# Deployment strategy that removes tables from uninstalled plugins

Tags: craft3, craft-features, deployment, git, commands

I have read the following article **best practices for deployments**.

https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/deployment-best-practices

here the following is recommended:

```
git pull
composer install
php craft up
```

The problem here is if I have uninstalled a plugin that has tables they are not removed with the "php craft up" command.

I also tried the following instead of `composer install` -> `php craft update/composer-install` because I thought that this would be taken into account here but unfortunately it is not taken into account here either.

Is there a way to remove the tables automatically if this plugin has been removed or do I have to uninstall the plugins manually?

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to do it in two separate steps…

1. **Uninstall the plugin via Craft.** Push those changes all the way through to your production environment.
2. **Uninstall the plugin via Composer.** Push those changes all the way through to your production environment.

By doing this as two distinct steps, it gives your production (and staging) environment a chance to properly run the plugin’s uninstall migrations *while the composer package is still available*. Once you remove the composer package (Step 2), the plugin won’t really know *how* to uninstall itself.